# How to show Dialog Box on another activity based on what you did in the previous activity

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I want to have a registration page and a create account page. After filling out your information in the create account page I want to go back to the registration page with a dialog box of either account creation successful or code resent.

As of now I am checking the response of the webserver and depending on the status it should show a dialog box then close the create account activity, showing the registration page in the background while the dialog box pops up and tells you that your account is created or the code is resent.

However as of now all it does is close my activity without showing the dialogs. I am assuming I would have to open the dialog on the registration page but I don't know how to ask if it was "created" or "resent". If you could give me some tips on how to show the appropriate dialog based on what I've said I would be very grateful.

Thank you

here is my code
*note* you press the button after you finish filling out the information

```
public void btnCreate(View v) throws Exception {
    // if we get to here we can send the information to the webserver

    String response = makeRequest(email.getText().toString(), fName
            .getText().toString(), lName.getText().toString());
    if (response != null) {
        org.json.JSONObject obj = new org.json.JSONObject(response);
          //response is created make created dialog
        if ("Created".equals(obj.getString("status"))) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateAccount.this)
                    .setTitle("Account Creation Successful")
                    .setMessage(
                            "An activation code has been sent to you. Please check your SPAM folder if you do not receive your activation code email")
                    .setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();
         // response is resend and sends the resend dialog
        } else if ("Resend".equals(obj.getString("status"))) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateAccount.this)
                    .setTitle("Code Resent")
                    .setMessage(
                            "Your activation code has been resent to your email.\n\nIf you are not receiving your activation code, our email is being blocked. Please email us at 'help@iphone-tracker.net' and we will manually send you a code.")
                    .setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();
        }
    }
      //finishes this activity and shows the registration activity (the one before create account)
    finish();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention yourself you should probably be creating the dialogboxes in the next activity. When starting a new activity you can pass extra information to the activity.

So doing something like:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
i.putExtra("login_successful", true); // Only true if they logged in.
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Then in you new activity you simply just retrieve the extra info sent from the earlier activity, by retrieving the bundle which was received when the new activity was created (onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)).

```
savedInstanceState = this.getIntent().getExtras();
boolean yes = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("login_successful");
```

Of course you can also put strings and other primitive types in the bundle as well.

Btw, you do not need to "finish" your current activity to show the next activity - I was thinking what if the user wants to log out or log in as another user? When you call the finish method on an activity it is removed from the activity stack and can't be retrieved until you've restarted the app completely.

Comment: works perfectly, i assume this is how you generally would transfer data from one activity to another.

Answer (score 0):

In your AlertDialog builder's setNeutralButton, set an DialogInterface.onClickListener and perform your logic that launches individual activities there.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you will want your registration to be a ActivityForResult and return a result. Based on the result the calling Activity can display different information (the result functions just like an intent so can have information packaged in it as well)